# PHPBB Robots.txt Rules?

Tags: php, robots.txt, forum, phpbb

I am currently editing my Robots.txt which looks like this:

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /adm/*
Disallow: /download/*
Disallow: /cache
Disallow: /files
Disallow: /viewforum.php?f=146
Disallow: /ucp.php
Disallow: /mcp.php
Disallow: /memberlist.php
Disallow: /config.php
Disallow: /cron.php
Disallow: /faq.php
Disallow: /report.php
Sitemap: http://www.website.com/app.php/sitemap.xml
```

I am wondering how to correctly do a few things however.

1) Would this correctly block search engines from accessing a forum area?

```
Disallow: /viewforum.php?f=146
```

I wanted one area hidden from search engines but the rest of the forum areas fully readable as normal.

2) How do you block access to the internal PHPBB folders and keep search engines out out admin? are these rules correct?

```
Disallow: /adm/*
Disallow: /download/*
```

3) Do the rules for php files work correctly?

```
Disallow: /ucp.php
```

Also is there anything else i should know or do?

Comment: adding that rule probably won't keep that hidden from search engines, they generally disobey the `robots.txt` file

Comment: Ok, but are the rules above correct?

Comment: @cmorrissey: Which (well known?) search engine disobeys robots.txt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
Disallow: /viewforum.php?f=146
```

disallows crawling of URLs whose paths **start with** `/viewforum.php?f=146`.

So URLs like these would not allowed to be crawled:

- `http://example.com/viewforum.php?f=146`
- `http://example.com/viewforum.php?f=1461`
- `http://example.com/viewforum.php?f=146a`
- `http://example.com/viewforum.php?f=146/foo`
- `http://example.com/viewforum.php?f=146&bar`
- …

(It works the same for `/ucp.php`, `/adm/`, and `/download/`, of course. Note that this means that the appeneded `*` is not needed, unless it’s actually part of the URL.)

So if the forum overview is at `http://example.com/viewforum.php?f=146`, it will be blocked. However, note that it might be the case that the same page is accessible from a different URL in addition, e.g. something like: `http://example.com/viewforum.php?someOtherParameter&f=146`

Also note that this will not necessarily block crawling of forum threads in that forum area (because they typically don’t start with this path). While conforming bots won’t crawl this forum area page, they might find links to the threads from some other place.

Comment: Thanks the info was really useful, so how would you block only area 146 of the forum but still allow 1461, 146a etc, is that possible?

Comment: Basically i was thinking about adding a like4like section to a forum i have and i know that some company's like google might possibly not like that type of thing as it could be considered blackhat so i just wanted the search engines to ignore it in case it made google etc dislike my site.

Comment: @zeddex: With the original robots.txt specification, it’s not possible. But many consumers support additional features for robots.txt, including Google: they interpret the `$` character as end ([see documentation](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062596?hl=en)), so `Disallow: /viewforum.php?f=146$` might do what you want. But bots that don’t have the same interpretation will interpret it literally, so they will be allowed to crawl `/viewforum.php?f=146` (because only `/viewforum.php?f=146$` is disallowed).

Comment: Ok thanks for the info, do you know if the like4like thing would get my forum google slapped? i was thinking about having sub4sub also and since they own youtube this might well be the case but does anyone know if it is ok or not?

Comment: @zeddex: Sorry, can’t help. Such a question would be off-topic for Stack Overflow anyway. The sister site [webmasters.se] might be of help, as SEO is on-topic there.

Answer (score -1):

You can only disallow directories via robots.txt, not files. 
First, remove the asterisks from the directories.

```
Disallow: /adm/
Disallow: /download/
```

As for the files you could add this to a < HEAD > section. It wont prevent the bot from fetching, but good bots should ignore it and move on.

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
```

Comment: Thanks, so with PHPBB how would you stop a search engine going through from a particular forum area? Would "Disallow: /viewforum.php?f=146" not work then?

Comment: That’s not true. Robots.txt doesn’t care if something is a directory, a file, or something else.